# Cannot access List<> within a List<>

Tags: c#

Generics rookie struggling to access a list inside a class which is contained in a list. Basically I am trying to list the occupations of people that the user entered (I am sure there is an easier way of doing this, but this code was made to practise generics).

**Class Code**

```
namespace GenericPersonClass
{
class GenericPerson<T>
{
    static public List<T> Occupations = new List<T>();
    string name, famName;
    int age;

    public GenericPerson(string nameS,string famNameS,int ageI, T Note)
    {
        name = nameS;
        famName = famNameS;
        age = ageI;
        Occupations.Add(Note);
    }

    public override string  ToString()
        {

            return "The name is " + name + " " + famName + " and they are " + age;
        }
  }
}
```

**Main Code**

```
namespace GenericPersonClass
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string token=null;
        string nameS, lastNameS,occS;
        int age;
        List<GenericPerson<string>> Workers = new List<GenericPerson<string>>();

        while (token != "no" || token != "No")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first name of the person to input");
            nameS = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the last name of the person " + nameS);
            lastNameS = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How old is " + nameS + " " + lastNameS);
            age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What is the occupation of " + nameS + " " + lastNameS);
            occS = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter more data?...Yes/No");
            Workers.Add(new GenericPerson<string>(nameS, lastNameS, age, occS));
            token = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You provide the following employment...\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Workers.Count; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \n", Workers[0].Occupations[i]); 
//This line above is shown as wrong by VS2010, and intellisense does not see Occupations...
        }

    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Leo

Comment: occupations is listed as a static on the Generic person class, so it is not a member variable that can be accessed on an instance.  Doing it this way is confusing, but I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, so offering meaningful advice is not easy.  You can access occupations using `GenericPerson<string>.Occupations` but I don't know if it is working as you intend it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're trying to access a **static** `List` from an instance variable.  That's the problem there.  You can access this directly by using the class **not** the instance.

Something like:

```
GenericPerson<string>.Occupations[i]
```

It doesn't have anything to do with the `List` - it's all about the **static** part.